# Classifying websites

Tags: web-crawler, web-scraping, classification

I need to scrape a thousand websites that share the same structure: they all have a menu, a title, some text and a rating, much like a blog. Unfortunately, they are also coded very differently and some are manually, so I cannot reutilize CSS selectors, and perhaps not even rely upon them.

I wonder how I can automatically classify them and save what is left of my hair. My first guess is to use lynx, or something text browser, to get some blocks of text and classify them according to their size.

Do you know of a better or more sophisticate approach?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/ to disassemble pages.

For classification, look, perhaps, at mahout.apache.org.

Comment: This is a great reference (thanks!). Just an FYI to others though that it really solves the first step, which is identifying the textual content of the document. It doesn't segment the content into fields or classify them.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to split the problem into two main parts.

Write the classification part as if all of the web sites were coded identically, with all the same structure.

Then write the scraping part so that it finds the actual structure of each web site, and maps that structure to your ideal structure from the classification part.

Comment: And while you are at it, solve the halting problem :-) This is a big, hard, job, and lots of people have put tons of time into it.

Comment: @bmargulies:  I had to look up the halting problem. :-)  The poster of the question did not provide enough detail for me to determine if his classification was practical.  I just gave the general "divide and conquer" answer to this type of question.

Comment: I should have left a smiley behind, sorry.